# Why authentication URL is not needed in other Oauth 2.0 grant type than authorization code?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have good knowledge of all Oauth grant type including use case but i have a question, i have seen many examples of authorization code so if i talk part step of authorization code grant type where client actually need to register him self with resource server so there he has to give two URLs

1.Redirect URL (Where client want to go with its authorization code)
2.Authentication URL (who gonna come to you)

so when client make actual call these things get validated so my question is, 
**Why auth 2.0 do not recommend to use authentication URL with other grant type, specially i am taking about client credential why we can not with it.**

Comment: add example code. avoid "I have knowledge of ....".

Comment: What is "Authentication URL"? At least, I cannot find it in RFC 6749 (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework).

Answer (score 0):

Authentication url is the url of 'auth server' where 'client' will redirect the 'user' for authentication and authorization.

Redirect Url is the url where 'user' is redirected (along with authorization code) by the 'auth server', after successful authentication and authorization.